# how to change sequence of li tags in ul tag?

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I use this [template](http://freehtml5.co/preview/?item=crew-free-html5-bootstrap-template) for my website  .I want in this template change sequence of li tags in ul tag that exist into top menu .[image]
 Is this possible? How do this?

Now :

```
Home,    About,    Services,    Features,    Testimonials,    Pricing,    Press
```

after change sequence most be :

> ```
> Press,Pricing,Testimonials,Features,Services,  About, Home
> ```

Comment: `float:right` for `li`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set `float:right` for `li` it will start from reverse